# Why does the virial theorem of quantum mechanics hold for the quantum oscillator but not the infinite square well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-states, virial-theorem

Why does the virial theorem of quantum mechanics hold for the quantum oscillator but not the infinite square well? The proof uses Ehrenfest's theorem, so I was wondering if it had something to do with the boundary conditions and how the particle does not behave classically. The theorem is as follows:

> Consider a quantum system where $\psi$ represents a stationary state which satisfies $d<\hat{x}\hat{p}>/dt=0$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> 2<\hat{T}>=<\hat{x}\frac{d\hat{V}}{dx}>.
> \end{equation}

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the virial theorem only applies to central force potentials that have a power law dependence on the radius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We calculate
   $$0~=~\frac{d}{dt}\langle \psi | \hat{x}\hat{p} | \psi\rangle
   ~=~\frac{1}{i\hbar}\langle \psi | [\hat{x}\hat{p},\hat{H}] | \psi\rangle $$
   $$~=~\frac{1}{i\hbar}\langle \psi \left| \hat{x}[\hat{p},\hat{V}]-[\hat{T},\hat{x}]\hat{p} \right| \psi\rangle
   ~=~2\langle \psi | \hat{T}| \psi\rangle-\langle\psi |\hat{x}\hat{V}^{\prime}(\hat{x}) | \psi\rangle.$$
2. OP wants to consider the [infinite square well potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box).
3. At first it might be tempting to consider the box interval $[-a,a]$ as full position space, and put the potential $V=0$ to zero everywhere. The problem with that approach is that the dynamics will not respect the boundary conditions $\psi(x=\pm a,t)=0$.
4. We want the boundary conditions to be consequences of the potential. Therefore the potential should be non-trivial.
5. The problem is therefore that the derivative $V^{\prime}(x)$ is not well-defined at the end-points of the box interval $[-a,a]$.
6. One possible regularization is to consider the [finite square well potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) 
   $$V(x)= V_0~\theta(|x|-a),\qquad V_0~<~\infty,$$ 
   on the real axis $\mathbb{R}$, where the theorem applies. Then the derivative $V^{\prime}(x)$ is a Dirac delta distribution. Next consider the limit $V_0\to\infty$.